# Is it possible to create table in postgresql dynamically?

Tags: postgresql, csv, create-table

I am trying to create a postgresql table from a csv file. The problem is, everytime I download the csv file it has different set of columns.

I thought of creating the table with the max columns and thus filling with 0s for the reports which donot have the extra columns. But I also donot know if in future there will be more columns in the csv file.

Expected: I should be able to dynamically create a table in postgres database with the required columns with respexct to the csv file generated for that day.

Comment: You could load the data into staging table that only has a single column, then use `string_to_array()` to split each row dynamically into array elements and check how may columns you get. Or use something like `file_text_array_fdw`: https://github.com/adunstan/file_text_array_fdw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of head scratching I came up with a solution that works fine for me, although I fear it doesn't adhere to the optimised coding standard.

About the method that I devised:

> Step 1: Drop the table

```
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE test;''')
```

> Step 2: Create an empty table

```
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE test();''')
```

> Step 3: Add columns along with their datatype in a for loop (As it will be a loop it will take time depending on the size of your report and thus I mentioned this method might not be he best one)

```
column_list = list(df.columns)
query = "ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN %s;"
for j in range(len(column_list)): 
    column_name = column_list[j]
    if df[column_list].dtypes[j] == 'object':
        datatype = 'varchar'
    elif df[column_list].dtypes[j] == 'float':
        datatype = 'real'
    elif report_df[column_list].dtypes[j] == 'int':
        datatype = 'int'
    elif df[column_list].dtypes[j] == 'bool':
        datatype = 'boolean'
    column = column_name + " " + datatype
    cur.execute(query, (AsIs(column),))
```

> Step 4:Use copy_from to copy the content from the desired file

```
    with open('.\test.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)  # skip the header row
    cur.copy_from(f, 'test', sep=',', columns=df.columns)
```